# Magento 2.1.7 Create Shipping label popup in Order grid view

Tags: shipping, magento-2.1.7, order-grid, popup, fedex

I am using Magento 2.1.7 inbuilt Fedex Create Shipping label in our client website. Is it possible to bring the "Create Shipping Label" side popup in Sales Order grid view? Currently, this button is showing after selecting View link of the particular order in order grid and then select Shipments ->Then have to choose to Create a shipping label.

Or else how to add a button in sales order grid view table and selecting that has to open the order details in a new window and make active the shipments tab to process the shipment fast.

Thank you.